# How to regenerate .desktop files for all applications that are currently installed on system

Tags: package-management, .desktop

I accidentally deleted all `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applications` directory.

Is there any way to restore/recover/regenerate it back for all the applications that I have currently installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: @derHugo: No, there are fare better (narrower and more likely to succeed) methods. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Since only files extracted from packages are supposed be stored in `/usr` (but not `/usr/local`) you can use the package manager to recover all those files:

- `dpkg-query -S [PATH]` lists all currently installed packages that (used to) have files in `[PATH]`.
- With a bit of mangling we can pass the package names to `apt-get` to reinstall them:

  ```sh
  xargs -r -d '\n' -a <(
      dpkg-query -S /usr/share/applications/ <&- |
      gawk -F '[,:][ \t]' '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if (!a[$i]++) print $i; }'
    ) -- sudo apt-get install --reinstall --
  ```
- If there are packages among them that weren't installed from a package repository but manually from a Deb package file, `apt-get` will complain that it can't find those particular packages and you'll have to install them anew.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Comment: +1 to partially balance lack of acceptance. The OP had signed on within the last week so it's not an abandoned question.